# Android Studio Could not find method runProguard() for arguments?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "- com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain --build-file /Users/Tom/Documents/Git_open_sources/android-material-drawer-template/app/build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/Tom/Documents/Git_open_sources/android-material-drawer-template/app/build.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method runProguard() for arguments [false] on BuildType_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, applicationIdSuffix=null, versionNameSuffix=null, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.741 secs

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.poliveira.apps.materialtests"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
//noinspection GradleDependency
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0"
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

Comment: What version of Android Studio and what version of the Android Gradle plugin is this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error:(26, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016385/error26-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-runproguard)

Comment: Android studio version is 1.0 rc

Comment: Even the same problem for me. Same AS 1.0 RC. I imported project which I was developing in the AS 0.8...

Answer (score 186):

I had the same problem after updating android studio to 1.0 RC 3.
I couldn't import my project to new version. i had to create a new project and add the files to the new project from the previous project manually.

After that I found a change in the gradle build file.

Here is the change:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Instead of "runProguard false" use "minifyEnabled false"

Comment: Works for me (after Updating to 1.0"final").
Should to be updated too: 
Gradle 2.2 (or above)
"SDK-Tools"
Support Repository
Support Library
Play Services
etc,etc,

Answer (score 35):

There is an update with Android Studio, you need to migrate your Gradle configurations : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0

- Replace runProguard with minifyEnabled
- Replace zipAlign with zipAlignEnabled
- etc...

Comment: Where do you find zipAlign?

Comment: It's on the build.gradle file (but it's optional, if you want to automatically zip align your APK)

Answer (score 12):

Works for me (after updating to 1.0 "final"):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Should to be updated too: 
Gradle 2.2 (or above),
"SDK-Tools",
Support Repository,
Support Library,
Play Services,
etc,etc,

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using runProguard in your gradle file, try using minifyEnabled. This should fix the issue. runProguard is deprecated and soon be stop working.

**NOTE - To use minifyEnabled, gradle should be updated to version 2.2 or above.**

Answer (score 2):

don't forget to change all renderscriptSupportMode to renderscriptSupportModeEnabled !

Also thoose who are in all your libs's project

Answer (score 0):

you need to do couple of things to migrate from 0.9 to 1.0
see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0