# What about BuildType_Decorated info in Gradle log?

Tags: android, gradle, android-build, android-build-type

When I start Gradle to build a test or debug application, It logs this at the very beginning.

```
BuildType_Decorated{name=release, ...
```

with attributs from the release builtType, While I ran the Debug buildType !

Any idea what this issue could be ?

```
compileSdkVersion ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION
buildToolsVersion ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

productFlavors {
    // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
    dev {
        // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
        // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
        // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
        minSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled false
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    prod {
        // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
        minSdkVersion ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION
        multiDexEnabled false
    }
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "fr.millezimsolutions.app.millezimu"
    targetSdkVersion ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
    minSdkVersion ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION
    versionCode ANDROID_BUILD_VERSION_CODE
    versionName ANDROID_BUILD_APP_VERSION_NAME
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        renderscriptOptimLevel 3
        signingConfig android.signingConfigs.release
        zipAlignEnabled true
        minifyEnabled true
        //  shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules-release.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        renderscriptOptimLevel 3
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        versionNameSuffix "debug"
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
        testProguardFile('proguard-rules-test.pro')
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` file here.

Comment: @jaydroider just added

Comment: Not sure but check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233800/android-studio-could-not-find-method-runproguard-for-arguments

Comment: @jaydroider nothing related as far I saw. My build just run fine, this is just the log that display wrong information : it run debug but display as release !!