# I am having an error whenever I try to add this

Tags: android

I am getting an error whenever I try to add "runProguard", here is my code:

```
 release {
            minifyEnabled false
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

and here is the error:

> Could not find method runProguard() for arguments [true] on
>   BuildType_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false,
>   testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false,
>   pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false,
>   renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true,
>   signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={},
>   mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[],
>   mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `minifyEnabled` and making it `true` will enable the Proguard. I'm guessing that `runProguard` ***[is depreciated-old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233800/android-studio-could-not-find-method-runproguard-for-arguments)*** that's why you get the error.

So add:

```
minifyEnabled true
```

Note that to use `minifyEnabled`, gradle should be updated to version `2.2` or above.

Comment: I added the "minifyEnabled true" to my code, although it still shows the same error, could you help me updating my gradle please?

Comment: Remove `runProguard` and then use : `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'` for updating the gradle and only this `minifyEnabled true` for proguard and then it should work.

Comment: Should I insert the: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0' on the line that I removed the runProguard?

Comment: "Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0] on BuildType_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=true, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType."

Comment: Okay, did it, now I get this error "Plugin with id 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0' not found."

Comment: Yes I am, 3.2 I guess, how do I give you the link?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I just got to the right file, and there was the line of code already there, what should I do?

Comment: Replace it with: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'` (new version)

Answer (score -1):

I have encounter a same problem some days ago and i solve this by making my `"minifyEnabled false"` this may help you try it

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't seem to work when I add the runProguard and I'm looking forward to publish my app on Play Store, any other suggestions mate?

Comment: have you update your android studio recently . ?? tell me the version code?

Comment: I have, two days ago, I'm using the 3.2 version.