# Crashlytics could not find the manifest when update build:gradle to 3.3.0

Tags: android, gradle

I use fabric crashlytics in my application and it works fine when com.android.tools.build:gradle is 3.2.1, until I update it to 3.3.0.

Now I meet the 'Crashlytics could not find the manifest', and find out that there is no AndroidManifest.xml created in build/intermediates/merged_manifest/.../merged.
I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542960/crashlytics-could-not-find-the-manifest) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978877/could-not-execute-build-using-gradle-with-crashlytics) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371480/crashlytics-could-not-find-the-manifest-with-fabric-properties), but did not solve my problem.
How do I fix it? Thanks.

Here is the lib.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    api('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

And here is the project gradle

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        ...
    }
}
```

And this is the error:
[image]

Comment: same problem here!

Comment: same for me!!!!

Comment: I ended up moving fabric to application module. it's working for me

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Have you tried configuring everything exactly as required for a Crashlytics setup with a library module and a base project? It seems the new Gradle plugin doesn't work if the setup is different from the one recommended [here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#set-up-a-library-subproject).

For me removing "`apply plugin: 'io.fabric'`" from the library's build.gradle file (but leaving it in the application build.gradle) solved this error.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've tried, but do not fix it. Besides, it works in gradle:3.2.1 so I think this configuration is fine. When update to 3.3.0 there is no AndroidManifest.xml created in intermediates/.../merged, so I guess that's why this error reported.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and fixed it for me like following, using Ionic 5, Capacitor and the [Cordova FirebaseX Plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex) (which references to Crashlytics) , may you need to adjust some paths to fit your environment:

1. Running the Gradlew Build Command like `./gradlew assembleDebug`.
2. Waiting for the error you get.
3. Copy the `AndroidManifest.xml` from `your-app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` to `your-app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`.
4. Re-Run the Gradlew Build Command, ./gradlew assembleDebug`.
5. Your build process should succeed now.

In my case with Ionic 5 and Capacitor the paths are:

- `android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`
- `android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It looks like a easier way to accomplished.

Comment: Thanks, had exactly the same issue and this fixed it. but now getting AAPT: error: resource color/accent (aka com.flexeventsapp.flex:color/accent) not found. have you run into this by any chance ?

Comment: @ihorbond I follow the step to got stuck there, have you been able to fix it yet?

Comment: @Zen3515 yes, I did. I created a color.xml (https://pastebin.com/6SmQYt4H) file and put in \android\app\src\main\res\values

Comment: @ihorbond thanks, so I ended up creating the color inside resource. I wanted to add that you must not rebuild the project, it will be reset back.

Comment: @Zen3515 yeah it's annoying, I had to add post script that I run after rebuild to copy the manifest again, the color.xml seems to stay though. Is that what you are doing too ?

Comment: You're already on the right way. It seems you have some plugins which require an additional config.xml with (in your case) color definitions. You need to copy this too, may you can create a small script for copying static resources.

Comment: Life saver Thanks bro !!

Answer (score 3):

I've got a fix for this while keeping Crashlytics dependencies out of the app module, but it's very hacky.

From what I can tell the io.fabric plugin primarily exists to generate a build ID for crashlytics, which is important to the Fabric platform but goes unused for Firebase. This, I assume, is vestigial functionality that will eventually be removed when Crashlytics completes its migration to Firebase, but in the meantime it's quite necessary simply because Crashlytics checks for it and crashes your app if it's not there.

So, I simply created a useless dummy build ID and removed all mention of the ui.fabric plugin from my modules, and it works! My code compiles and reports crashes to the firebase console as it did previously, and I can update to android gradle plugin v3.3.0+ with no issues.

---

The specific steps I took were:

Add this to the main/res/values.xml file in the module that uses crashlytics:

`<string name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id" translatable="false">RANDOM_UUID</string>`

And remove all usages of the io.fabric gradle plugin, as well as the classpath dependency on the gradle plugin (as you no longer use it).

---

Note that, as I said, this is very hacky. I'd suggest testing this thoroughly if you take this approach for your project. There might be some functionality that does still use the build ID and this would cause it to break.

EDIT: after further investigation I believe that doing this will prevent crashlytics from uploading your mapping file, which means you will have to manually deobfuscate stack traces. This is still an option at least, but does seem to have drawbacks. Also worth noting that you can also simply use:

`<string name="com.crashlytics.RequireBuildId">false</string>`

instead of providing a dummy build ID.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I fix it according to @Roman Potapov 's answer. 
First, move plugin to app.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: ‘io.fabric' 

Then keep this in my lib.gralde
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
api('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

Comment: Yes, that should work as well, my point when providing this solution is that it keeps all of Crashlytics in the library module. My whole reason for using a library module in the first place was to completely decouple my code from firebase / crashlytics.

Comment: Yes, That make sense.